# poedit doesn't recognize keyword within complex(curly) syntax , braces

Tags: php, syntax, poedit

I've encountered a problem that PoEdit can't recognize keyword if it's inside braces syntax. example:
`$test = "{$view->translate('invisible')} some text around";`

PoEdit v1.7.4

I have a lot of strings inside heredoc syntax and etc. if i use braces then those variables are invisible to PoEdit scan. Is it possible to fix somehow ?

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be that `xgettext` (which Poedit uses; not really a Poedit question per se) doesn't try to interpret *string literals*. You may want to [submit a bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=gettext) about the lack of support for interpolated strings to GNU gettext.

But fixing it is simple enough: just don't use interpolation:

```
$test = $view->translate('invisible') . ' some text around';
```

Comment: Yeah, i know this fix.It suits me well with simple strings like this example. But our company have to localize in-dev state product and they use a lot of long heredoc blocks of code, so it's a real pain in the ass, and i don't think they will like the idea to refactor it like this and especially to write in a new manner. currently i have this fix and another is to predefine variable with translation and then use it in string, which is also quite messy.

Comment: Well, in that case, it's as I wrote above: you should file a bug report (and I'm sure GNU gettext folks would appreciate a patch too!).